# Currently Try to intertwine Parse push into my swift app using Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So I'm running into an issue trying to get Parse Push to work with my app. here is a list of things i have done to try and make it work.

- I have revoked and re-did all certificates
- I have reinstalled the newest certificate into parse site under settings for push
- I've deleted and reinstalled my APP ID on Xcode

I'm new to this so I'm not sure where to begin, I can get the app to come up on my phone, and it lets me do my events and stuff but when I go to push on parse site it won't let me do anything that there is no registered devices so I'm not sure if my code is incorrect or what not..

Any help would be great guys..

Thank you

PS I have my parse code in the actual code i just removed for posting purposes.

Here is my current code I have in AppDelegate.swift file

import UIKit
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Set App ID
    Parse.setApplicationId("Your Id Here", clientKey: "Your Key Here")



 UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications(); let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound], categories: nil); UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings); UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()


    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated:true)

  return true
```

}

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.channels = ["global"]
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Have you seen and followed this...https://parse.com/apps/quickstart?app_id=prozone#parse_data/mobile/ios/swift/existing ? Also, if something isn't working please tell us what is actually happening. If you're getting errors then post the error log. Much easier to work out what's happening that way.

Comment: "Please verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your signing certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018) <---- here is the most recent error i just got. So I deleted everything my app id, my certificates, all provision profiles and started over this time it ran all the way through the deal and said that

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr
You can try this for some info [iOS Swift Push](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/tree/master/iOS) or [Parse Push QuickStart](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/ios/swift/existing)

Long part

Make your app register for remote notifications by adding the following in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: function (if you haven't already):

```js
    import parse


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

Parse.setApplicationId("YOURS",
      clientKey: "Yours")

        // Register for Push Notitications
        if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
            // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
            // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
            // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

            let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
            let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
            var pushPayload = false
            if let options = launchOptions {
                pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
            }
            if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
                PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
            }
        }
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        } else {
            let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }

}
```

If all this is in your appdelegate.swift and it doesn't work then there is something wrong with your certificates more than likey.

Comment: i tried to use that code you posted but it said that the fund app "did fail" was messing with pervious value. I changed it back deleted all pervious app ids' provision id's and re did everything and now i get this... "Please verify that your device’s clock is properly set, and that your signing certificate is not expired. (0xE8008018) <---- here is the most recent error i just got. So I deleted everything my app id, my certificates, all provision profiles and started over this time it ran all the way through the deal and said that